# Python if statement in for statement skipping

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, if-statement

The following is what I have currently in python 3:

```
a = 0
b = 0
c = 0

M = 100
T = 100

mth = [[25,50,100], [70,50,88], [5,10,33]]
for i in mth:

    m = i[0]  
    t = i[1]  
    h = i[2]  

    if a+m <= M:
        a = a+m
        M = M-m
    else:
        continue

    if b+t <= T:
        b = b+t

    else:
        continue

    c = c + h
print(a,b,c)
```

My problem with the above is that it should add the first two tuples and print

```
95 100 188
```

However for some reason when the for loop reaches the second tuple in mth it checks if a+m <= M and eventhough its true at this point, it goes straight to the Else statement and ends up adding the third tuple together to give

```
30 60 133
```

I tried removing the third one, but it still skips over the second tuple.
Is there something silly I'm doing here? Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the first iteration, the value of `M` becomes 75, not 100. Thus in the second iteration, `a + m = 25 + 70 = 95 > M`, not `<= M` as you expected.

Comment: *facepalm* I knew it was something small and dumb. Thanks a lot